# Ternary to Short-Circuit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to become more concise with my code and one of the things I never really understood was Short-Circuit Eval. I think it's because when I research the question it doesn't click because usually the examples are pseudo code and I can't wrap my head around it.

The below code is a pull from an AJAX script I wrote. What would be an equivalent Short Circuit Expression? And if you can, please explain in layman's terms how it's evaluating.

```
var xhr; (XMLHttpRequest) ? 
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest : 
xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Comment: i think the boolean is checking whether or not `XMLHttpRequest` is supported by the browser, if not, it creates it as an `ActiveXObject` instead.

Comment: var xhr = (XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

Comment: actually, if XMLHttpRequest is not supported, this is an error that throws...

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a good example of a time to use short-circuiting to get the desired results. You would use a short-circuit when the value you're evaluating for truthiness is one of the possible values to be assigned.

Comment: @NicholasThomson agreed, not even to mention, that this is an IE6 issue...

Comment: without ternary:  
`var xhr = new ( self.XMLHttpRequest && XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the example you've posted isn't a great way to illustrate short-circuiting. I know you say you've seen other examples, but maybe one more will do the trick.

If you had something like this using a ternary:

```
var fruit = apple ? apple : banana;
```

The intent of this code is "If apple is truthy, I want fruit to equal apple. Otherwise, fruit should equal banana."

The equivalent way to do it using short-circuiting would look like this:

```
var fruit = apple || banana
```

This code does the same thing because of the way boolean logic works. The `||` operator means OR. You probably already know that. But if you think about it, as long as one side of the `||` operator is true, the whole statement is true. So if the first item in the expression is true it doesn't even bother checking the second half of it. There would be no point, it would be true either way, why not save some runtime?

And the assignment works because of instead of coercing (apple || banana) to a boolean, it just returns the first truthy value and any time you use it in a conditional statement it will be coerced anyways.

Here are some more examples of short circuiting

```
(1 || 2) // 1
(0 || 5) // 5 (0 is falsey)
(false || 0) // If the first value is falsey, the expression evaluates to the second item, whether its truthy or falsey.
(5 || 0) // 5
```

EDIT:

And just to drive home why its called short-circuiting

```
function doWork(){
    console.log('Hello!');
}

(true || doWork())
```

Nothing would be printed in the console, the `doWork` function would never run. Because to the computer the second half of this expression might as well not exist.

Comment: It's true this wasn't exactly what I asked, but given that my example was unknowingly not great code to derive into a short circuit eval, I understand. This completely answered my questions about Short Circuits. Based on your example I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ja2cL3t5/ - and spent about 10 minutes adjusting the variable apple to see the results. It was one of those moments where things finally clicked and I was a little angry at myself that I couldn't grasp the concept earlier. I really appreciate it. Thanks for stepping outside the box.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can also do short circuiting with falsey values and the and operator: `(5 && 3) // 3` or `(0 && 5) //0` because for similar reasons, there's no point evaluating the second half of an `&&` expression if the first half is falsey. Just one more thing to play around with.

Answer (score 1):

A short circuit allows you to only execute part of the expression, if it matches (or doesn't match). In this case, we're trying to see if xhr is valid, otherwise, we'll create a new ActiveXObject. If it matches (new XMLHttpRequest), then we only have to execute that part-- short circuiting the expression.

You can also look at it as saying

```
var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest && new XMLHttpRequest) || (new ActiveXObject);
```

Comment: or `var xhr = new (XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject);`, but neiter solve the RefError issue, and ActiveXObject needs an argument passed to it, unlike ajax.

Comment: Agreed, but OP asked 'What would be an equivalent Short Circuit Expression?'

Comment: According to w3's example, it should work: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Comment: well "new XMLHttpRequest" will throw if the browser doesn't define _XMLHttpRequest_, like IE6 for example. in fact, other than IE6, there's no reason to fork at all...

Comment: It won't work because if XMLHttpRequest is undefined you'll get a ReferenceError instead of falling back to ActiveXObject

Comment: Updated my answer, @dandavis, your suggestion gives me the same result.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 Thank you. It looks pretty clean and makes a lot more sense now. I realize this may not have been the best example to work from, but my only question is, with the new ActiveXObject, would it work? The ActiveXObject as far as I understand requires params.  I'd test it out, but I don't have an early enough version of IE. If not that's fine I can just use this an educational example because it does do a great job to make light of the theory behind a short circuit eval.

Comment: The easiest way to check is to sign up for a free account at Sauce Labs (https://saucelabs.com/features#features-manual-testing), open one of the browsers you'd like to test this on, open the console for that browser, and paste that code on in.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 Thanks! Unfortunately I'll have to test it out later on. The server the code is hosted on is running on a local network that I don't have the permissions to connect saucelabs to. I will test it out on my home server when I get the chance.